# WordPress Cannot save Permalink shows 404 error

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, web-hosting

I have hosted a domain in Linux Apache 2.4.16 web server and installed WordPress in it. Now I cannot update Permalink from default `(date/time/%postname%/)` to `/%postname%/` or custom structure. Only Plain type gets saved. I am getting 404 error.

> > 404 Page not found

I have cleared everything in the server contents, posts, plugins, even ssl too and remove and install WordPress,... But I am still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems all the things you did are correct in this context. Have you checked whether the **mod_rewrite** module is on in **Apache**. You can check that by writing the `phpinfo` function in a file at your server. 
Check [Screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2832188/4288fe8290c7338f93191d51726efbc7)

[Read](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to `.htaccess` file. Through Linux command line. At first navigate to the project folder,

```
cd /var/www/html/project-folder
```

Then give 777 permission to `.htaccess` file. By this below command,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .htaccess
```

Then edit .htaccess file with the below code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And then update the permalink settings 2 times from the wordpress admin panel.

Comment: I tried already. And i tried your suggestion again with fresh WordPress install. No Luck, same error.

Comment: Added screenshots of .htaccess file and its permission in the question.